# jQuery - check proper time format

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input field where the user enters a time in format mm:hh. The format is specified inside the field (default value 09:00) but I still want to perform a client-side check to see if the format is correct.

Since the existing client-side validation is in jQuery, I'd like to keep this in jQuery as well.

I'm mainly a PHP programmer so I need some help writing this one in an optimal manner.

I know I can check each individual character (first two = digits, third = ':', last two = digits) but is there a way to do it more elegantly, while also checking the hour count is not larger than 23 and the minute count isn't larger than 59?

In PHP I would use regular expressions, I assume there's something similar for jQuery?

Something like this makes sense to me:

```
([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]
```

But I'm not too familiar with jQuery syntax so I'm not sure what to do with it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can use regex in JavaScript too:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp

use
.search() - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_search.asp

or .match() - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp

or .replace() - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

**EDIT:**

```
<script>
    var regexp = /([01][0-9]|[02][0-3]):[0-5][0-9]/;
    var correct = ($('input').val().search(regexp) >= 0) ? true : false;
</script>
```

**EDIT2:**

here the documentation of regexpobject in javascript:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

```
<script>
    var regexp = /([01][0-9]|[02][0-3]):[0-5][0-9]/;
    var correct = regexp.test($('input').val());
</script>
```

**EDIT3:**

fixed the regexp

Comment: Thanks, that works. Just one problem, it allows for any two-digit number to be entered as "hh". For instance it accepts 77:00 as a proper time. I can't see why it could be looking at the regex, can you?

Comment: try to use `/([01][0-9]|[02][0-3]):[0-5][0-9]/`

Comment: @robert The reason it was returning true for `77:00` is because it was matching the `7:00` part of the string. In order to force the entire string to be matched use [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) such as `^` (beginning of string) and `$` (end of string) eg `/^([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$/` - this will fail to match `77:00` (or any part of it).

Answer (score 4):

In JavaScript, regexes are delimited by `/`. So you would do...

```
var isValidTime = /([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]/.test(inputString);
```

Your regex seems to make sense for validating any 24H time in HH:mm format. However as I state in my comment under Andreas's answer - this will return true if *any part* of the string matches. To make it validate the entire string, use anchors to match the start and end of the string also eg...

```
var isValidTime = /^([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$/.test(inputString);
```

To actually pull the matches you would need to use the [`string.match`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html) JS function.

Oh - and please be aware that jQuery *is* Javascript - it's just a library of very useful stuff! However this example contains no reference to the jQuery library.

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript you can use [`yourstring.match(regexp)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to match a string against a regular expression.

I have very limited RegEx-experience, so I cant help you with the pattern, but if you have that set `.match()` should be all it takes.

Answer (score 2):

A different approach, but using an extra javascript lib instead of regular expressions:

```
var valid = moment(timeStr, "HH:mm", true).isValid();
```

I guess if you already use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) in your project, there's no downside.

And since you didn't specifically request an answer using regular expressions, I think it's valid to mention.